# How to save a document using JavaScript in Adobe Acrobat?

Tags: javascript, adobe, acrobat

Basically what I'm trying to accomplish is when the document gets printed it will save in a specific location with the text in a text field.

How can I accomplish this? What I've been seeing will basically replace the document and not create a new document each time on print.

Comment: Could you be more specific..? What does Adobe Acrobat have to do with printing, presumably, from the browser?

Comment: Well basically I can click on Print and when that action happens I would like the document to also save. It's not in a browser, I have a PDF file and I'm launching it with Acrobat.

Comment: What JavaScript are you using now? There is a saveAs function on the Doc object you can use in Javascript that allows you to specify a path - presumably including a file name?